# I am using multiprocessing pool to updte matrix values, but the values don't change

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have a simple function that takes a matrix 'h' and some more arguments, and adds some computed vector on top of a single column of the matrix. Then I apply that function for each column of a matrix - I have a code that does this sequentially and everything is fine there; but, since the column-wise operations are independent I want to do it in parallel. However, when I apply the same function with 'multiprocessing.Pool()', the values of the matrix don't change from the initial value.

Bellow goes a script with both sequential and parallel implementation. In the end, the values of matrices 'h1' and 'h2' should be the same, but they are not, and actually 'h2' has the same value that it had in the beginning (that is, as a matrix 'deltas').

I am not a programmer, and don't have much experience with multiprocessing library, so maybe I am doing something stupid here...

```
from  multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing import set_start_method
import time
import numpy as np
from functools import partial

def h_single_ctr(ctr,C,keys1,bs1,h):
    indices1 = np.where(keys1[:,1]==ctr)[0]
    indices2 = np.where(keys1[:,0]==ctr)[0]
    h[:,ctr] += (C[keys1[:,0][indices1]]).dot(bs1[indices1])
    h[:,ctr] += (C[keys1[:,1][indices2]]).dot(bs1[indices2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m,n = 100,15000
    deltas = np.random.rand(n,m)
    C = np.random.rand(m)
    mbs = 150
    bs1 = np.random.rand(mbs,n)
    keys1 = np.random.randint(m,size=(mbs,2))
        
    # Sequential    
    tic = time.time()
    h1 = 0. + deltas
    for ctr in range(m):
        # Update each column of a matrix h1, using function h_single_ctr
        h_single_ctr(ctr,C,keys1,bs1,h1)
    toc = time.time()    
    print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc-tic))

    # Multiprocessing / Pool
    tic = time.time()
    h2 = 0. + deltas
    p = Pool(5)
    # Update each column of a matrix h2, using function h_single_ctr, in parallel
    p.map(partial(h_single_ctr,C=C,keys1=keys1,bs1=bs1,h=h2), range(m))
    p.close()
    p.join()
    toc = time.time()    
    print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc-tic))
    
    print(np.linalg.norm(h1-h2))
```

Comment: multiprocessing works by spawning separate processes with their own memory space. Editing the matrix in another process does not edit the matrix in your main process.

Comment: Multiprocessing does incur overheads from spawning the other processes and copying the  matrix over into the other process' memory space so if your matrix is large enough to require this level of parallelization, you'd need to collect the results back and update your original matrix in the main process. Alternatively, you can look at Cython for GIL-less multithreading within the same process on memoryviews (np arrays can be used).

Comment: Thanks @rcshon , in this example the matrix size is small, but I also need to see for different dimensions, so I think that the overhead will not be a problem for some of the cases. But then, how do I collect the results? I should add a return to my function, and then call it in a list comprehension manner like `[h_single_ctr(ctr,C,keys1,bs1,h2) for ctr in range(m)]` ?

Comment: You can use `from multiprocessing import Queue` and put the result in the queue or use the `from multiprocessing import Manager` to create shared dictionary for your main process to read from. The interprocess communication is abstracted away from you, making it pretty simple to implement.

Comment: A side note is you probably want to only dispatch only a subset of your matrix that needs to be worked on to prevent sending the huge matrix over to each process. Another note is processes have to be attended to by a CPU core, so spawning 100 processes like in your code doesn't make much sense. You should probably spawn like 3 cores in a quad-core system.

Comment: Again, I think you'd benefit more from GIL-less multithreading instead of spawning processes on the fly. You can check out Numba or Cython which helps you do that at the C-level without the GIL but also keeping your code concise. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new variable for each process and then add them all on top of your global h. Notice that you need to have a one-dimensional array, and not a matrix within the process.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Array
from threading import Thread
import time
import numpy as np

def h_single_ctr(ctr,C,keys1,bs1,h):
    indices1 = np.where(keys1[:,1]==ctr)[0]
    indices2 = np.where(keys1[:,0]==ctr)[0]
    h[:,ctr] += (C[keys1[:,0][indices1]]).dot(bs1[indices1])
    h[:,ctr] += (C[keys1[:,1][indices2]]).dot(bs1[indices2])
    
def h_single_ctr2(ctr,C,keys1,bs1):
    indices1 = np.where(keys1[:,1]==ctr)[0]
    indices2 = np.where(keys1[:,0]==ctr)[0]
    res = (C[keys1[:,0][indices1]]).dot(bs1[indices1])
    res += (C[keys1[:,1][indices2]]).dot(bs1[indices2])
    return res
def h_multiple_ctr(n,C,ctr_list,keys1,bs1,h):
    for i in range(len(ctr_list)):
        ctr = ctr_list[i]
        res = h_single_ctr2(ctr,C,keys1,bs1)
        h[(i*n):((i+1)*n)] += res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    m,n = 100,15000
    deltas = np.random.rand(n,m)
    C = np.random.rand(m)
    mbs = 150
    bs1 = np.random.rand(mbs,n)
    keys1 = np.random.randint(m,size=(mbs,2))
    
    num_processes = 3
    col_processes = [[i for i in range(j,m,num_processes)] for j in range(num_processes)] # column indices that each process will take

    # Sequential    
    tic = time.time()
    h1 = 0. + deltas
    for ctr in range(m):
        # Update each column of a matrix h1, using function h_single_ctr
        h_single_ctr(ctr,C,keys1,bs1,h1)
    toc = time.time()    
    print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc-tic))
    
    # Multiple processes
    tic = time.time()
    h2 = 0. + deltas
    for pid in range(num_processes):
        hi = Array('d', [0]*(len(col_processes[pid])*n), lock=False)
        p = Process(target=h_multiple_ctr, args=(n,C,col_processes[pid],keys1,bs1,hi))
        p.start()
        p.join()
        h2[:,col_processes[pid]] += np.reshape(hi,(len(col_processes[pid]),n)).T
        
    toc = time.time()    
    print('Done in {:.4f} seconds'.format(toc-tic))
    
    print(np.linalg.norm(h1-h2))
```